# How to create intervals for a specific df column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
     CODE      STATION      AVERAGE
0    109014   BUENA VISTA        29
1    111022        HUAYAN        28
2    111023          ﾑAﾑA        28
3    112058       PACARAN        28
4    111004  ALCANTARILLA        24
..      ...           ...       ...
263  114050        ANANEA        18
264  113100  VILCASHUAMAN        17
265  113101     CHILCAYOC        16
266  114093        PUTINA        16
267  114096     CUYO CUYO        16
```

I want to create a new column with intervals. So i'm creating this code:

```
df.loc[df['AVERAGE'] == 30.0, 'INTERVAL'] = '[30]'
df.loc[(df['AVERAGE'] < 30.0)&((df['AVERAGE'] >= 25.0)), 'INTERVAL'] = '<30-25]'
df.loc[(df['AVERAGE'] < 25.0)&((df['AVERAGE'] >= 20.0)), 'INTERVAL'] = '<25-20]' 
df.loc[(df['AVERAGE'] < 20.0)&((df['AVERAGE'] >= 15.0)), 'INTERVAL'] = '<20-15]' 
df.loc[(df['AVERAGE'] < 15.0)&((df['AVERAGE'] >= 10.0)), 'INTERVAL'] = '<15-10]' 
df.loc[(df['AVERAGE'] < 10.0)&((df['AVERAGE'] >= 5.0)), 'INTERVAL'] = '<10-5]'
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this? Also i want to know if there is a way that python can identify the value of intervals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `pd.cut`

```
df['out'] = pd.cut(df.AVERAGE,range(5,35,5), right=False)
```

Comment: And how can i include the [30] interval?

Comment: @Javier change it to range(5,40,5) and you konw the last bin is 30 ~ :-)